# Breaking a line with flexbox centering?

Tags: css, position, flexbox

I'm trying to vertically/horizontally center my Title with the Subtitle directly beneath it. Here was my attempt:

```css
html, body, h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Main Title</h1>
  <span>Subtitle</span>
</div>
```

As you can see, the subtitle is in the same line as the `h1`, I'm trying to get it to go beneath it. I've tried setting `h1` to `display: block;` but that seems to not work when using `display: flex` on the `container`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `flex-direction: column` on `container`

```css
html, body, h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Main Title</h1>
  <span>Subtitle</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, I see. IDK why I thought there was only row and row-reverse. Thanks very much, will accept when I can.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `flex-direction` to `column` is one solution. It's already provided in another answer.

In some cases, if `flex-direction: row` is preferred (or a necessity), you can add `flex-wrap: wrap` to the container and give the first item a 100% width, which forces the second item to the next line.

```css
body, h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;           /* NEW */
  align-content: center;     /* NEW */
  text-align: center;        /* NEW */
}

h1 { flex: 0 0 100%; }       /* NEW */
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>Main Title</h1>
  <span>Subtitle</span>
</div>
```